# How we create Two Columns per row in List View

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How we create Two Columns per row in List View and Bind Data With Row?
i want create a list where each row has two columns and each columns bind with single data template.

Comment: you can use grid.using grid you can create like table structure. [https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/).

Answer (score 3):

you can use like this.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstName"
          Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.Column="0" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListObject,Mode=TwoWay}"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          BackgroundColor="White">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid RowSpacing="0"
                  Padding="15,8,0,8"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">             
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                 
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{Binding FieldName}"
                       Font="12" />
                <Label Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding FieldName}" 
                       Font="12"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```